# I need my image slide in/out translate animation to loop in android

Tags: android, translate-animation

I'm trying to get an image slideshow-type animation in my code, where an image slides in from the left of an ImageView, stays in the center for 4 seconds, then slides out to the right. But at the same time as the image exits the ImageView, I want a following image to slide in from the left and basically keep looping round.

It should work a lot like the main display on this page: http://developer.android.com/index.html

Except that it slides in from the left, not the right, and there shouldn't be any buttons.

So far I can get an image to slide in from the left and stay for 4 seconds and then the next image comes along and does the same etc. But I really need the continuous looping functionality if it's possible?

Here is my code:

HomeScreenFragment.java

```
private int [] Img_Ids = {
        R.drawable.splash0, R.drawable.splash1, 
        R.drawable.splash2, R.drawable.splash3      
};

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home_screen,
            container, false);

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AnimateandSlideShow();
        }
    };

    int delay = 0;
    int period = 2500;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
        }
    },delay, period);
 }



private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

    slidingimage = (ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.singOff);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(Img_Ids[currentimgindex%Img_Ids.length]);

    currentimgindex++;

    Animation slideInImage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.custom_slide);

    slidingimage.startAnimation(slideInImage);

}
```

custom_slide.xml:

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="500" />
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll probably want to add another animation, similar to `custom_slide.xml` but to control exiting.  For example, this is your original `custom_slide.xml`, which I would recommend renaming to something like `slide_in_from_left.xml`:

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="500" />
```

And you should add one named something like `slide_out_to_right.xml`:

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="500" />
```

Then you need to trigger the slide-out animation for the previous image whenever you trigger the slide-in animation for the next image.  This would mean adding a *second* ImageView resource in addition to the one you called `R.id.singOff`.  You can then alternate between the two, sliding one in while sliding the other out, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of helpful. I'm pretty new to programming so would you be able to tell me how this is achieved, is it as simple as making another method like my AnimationandSlide() method, but with both animations in, and then calling that method after the first?